# Passing an array of structure elements

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am doing some vector computations using the [NE10 library](https://github.com/projectNe10/Ne10). The library has a type for a complex number which is a struct like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    ne10_float32_t r;
    ne10_float32_t i;
} ne10_fft_cpx_float32_t;
```

I would like to have a function, which takes an array of these structs (1D array of complex numbers) as an argument and performs a vector computation for only the r or i elements of the array. Here is an example of such function to get an idea:

```
void multiple_real_part_by_two(ne10_fft_cpx_float32_t* output, 
    ne10_fft_cpx_float32_t* input, ne10_uint32_t array_length)
{
    ne10_mulc_float_c (&output->r, &input->r, 2.0, array_length)
}
```

So I would like the output array to be like the input array, but each of the r elements should be multiplied by two. The problem is, the way the function is written above does not work, and leads to a segmentation fault. I think the problem is in how I am trying to pass an array of the r elements to the `ne10_mulc_float_c()` function.

The `ne10_mulc_float_c()` function takes as arguments pointers to two arrays of type `ne10_float32_t` of size `array_length`. The elements of the input array are multiplied by the number passed as the third argument, and the result is stored in the output array. The documentation can be found [here.](http://projectne10.github.io/Ne10/doc/group__MUL__VEC.html)

Is there a way I could do this? I know I could just do this in a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
    output[i].r = input[i].r * 2.0
}
```

but I don't want to do this since performance is critical, which is why I am trying to use the vector operations provided by NE10 in the first place.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: c or c++ pick one please. These are different programming languages.

Comment: The problem is that `&output->r` is not the start of an array of `ne10_float_t` values; it is a pointer to an element in an array of structures.  You can't usefully use the `ne10_mulc_float_c()` function for this job because of this.

Comment: I don't see any multiplication function in those docs for an array of complex numbers. You may have to do a loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you give `ne10_mulc_float_c()` arguments of the right type, but which do not match the assumptions.

According to the [library's documentation page](https://projectne10.github.io/Ne10/doc/group__MUL__VEC.html), the function is defined as:

```
ne10_result_t   ne10_mulc_float_c (ne10_float32_t *dst, ne10_float32_t *src, 
                                  const ne10_float32_t cst, ne10_uint32_t count)
```

with the following arguments:

```
[out]   dst Pointer to the destination array
[in]    src Pointer to the source array
[in]    cst The constant to multiply by
[in]    count   The number of scalar values to be processed
```

This means that the function assumes that dst and src are are pointers to arrays of `count` CONSECUTIVE floating point numbers.

Unfortunately, the is is not the case with the arguments that you pass: 
`&output->r` and `&input->r` are both pointers to one single float.  So as soon at this function tries to access the second item in the array it expects, it code goes beyond the array's real bounds and this is UB.  This is why it doesn't work and you get the segmentation fault.

Your for-loop is just fine. Don't forget:

> [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization). 
>   -- [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth)

Comment: Thank you! This is what I figured myself, but your explanation made it more clear.

I wonder if I can use the function `ne10_mulc_vec2f_c()` for my purpose, since it takes as arguments pointers to arrays of type

    `typedef struct
    {
        ne10_float32_t x;
        ne10_float32_t y;
    } ne10_vec2f_t;`

Could I pass to this function pointers to my arrays of `ne10_fft_cpx_float32_t` 's since the struct elements are of the same type? The docs are on the same [page as above](http://projectne10.github.io/Ne10/doc/group__MUL__VEC.html)

Comment: In the header file, I can see that ne10_vec2f_t and ne10_fft_cpx_float32_t have exactly the same structure (with the exception of the member names) so you could try this becasue you'll have the same trivially copyable layout for both.  WIth C there are big chances that this works.  With C++ there are chances that this fails if the function is implemented using std::copy() algorithm.  In both cases, this would not be guaranteed to work, for example if both structure would evolve differently with different hidden members,